ProxySQL to connect to multiple Mysql clusters
I need to integrate Teleport with our existing MySQL instances. We operate multiple group replication clusters, but integrating them with Teleport proves challenging as it requires SSL, which I'm unable to enable for all clusters at the moment. To address this, I plan to implement ProxySQL in front of our MySQL instances with SSL enabled. This should facilitate integration with Teleport. However, I'm unsure if it's feasible to connect to multiple MySQL clusters using a single instance of ProxySQL. I'm aware that spinning up multiple ProxySQL services is an option, but I'm exploring alternative approaches.
FYI:

i cannot enable SSL because there are existing applications connected to this mysql and that needs changes in its client as well , which is not possible at the moment.
teleport is used for our community to connect to mysql instance for data debugging purpose.
understand proxy sql is not intended to use as above , but its a workaround to integrate teleport to connect self hosted mysql servers.

tried a couple of other tools like stunnel , haproxy , nothing worked as expected as either using the tools had issues with mysql , or enabling ssl with these tools had issues . ProxySQL was easier to setup SSL, and Teleport identified the mysql instance behind easily and was quicker.
